# is it possible to install ubuntu desktop and ubuntu server in the same computer?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am new to ubuntu, i want to know if i can install ubuntu desktop version and ubuntu server version in the same computer.
Im excited to learn of the new technology (new to me) and to start coding my own cyber security software

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you don't install both. You just install the "missing" packages.

In general, the only difference is that on the Server edition you don't have a desktop and related packages (X, word processor, graphical browser, etc.) and on the Desktop edition you don't have server related packages.

You can start from the Server edition and then install the desktop packages (this is the hard way) or you can start from the Desktop edition and then install server packages (e.g. apache2, ssh, php, MySQL, etc.).

Since Ubuntu 12.04 both editions also use the same kernel.

For more details, see [Ubuntu Server FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq)

Answer (score 0):

I think virtualization could be a good answer for your usecase. You can install a classic desktop version of Ubuntu, and install a Ubuntu Server inside a virtual machine on your desktop.

Have a look at [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/); you can install it pretty easily on Ubuntu with a simple `apt-get install virtualbox`